# In Ruby, if array string equals any of the second array string, then how can I delete from file or array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I'm trying to read a file of key words (1 word per line), and I put each word into an array. I am trying to delete any of the words that match the 'useless words' array, so my code reads:

```
useless_words = ["a","the","at","we","are","be","i","what", "want","you","oh","u"]

word1 = []

puts file2.count

file2.each do |file|
  word1 << file
end

word1.each do |word|
  useless_words.each do |word2|
    if word.to_s == word2.to_s true
      word1.delete_if { |word| 
        word.to_s == word2.to_s
      }
    end
  end
end

puts word1.count
```

My word1 count should be slightly less than file1 count, however my response is:
file2.count = 39
and word1.count = 0

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok your code is pretty obscure for me, it will be nice if you put more comments next time and/or maybe have a better convention naming for yours variables.

I think your problem is due to the fact that the word you have in word1 contain the `\n`.

Here is my solution

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

useless_words = ["a","the","at","we","are","be","i","what", "want","you","oh","u"]

words_in_file = []
File.open("file.txt", "r") do |infile|
  while (line = infile.gets)
    words_in_file << line.strip
  end
end

puts "Words in file: #{words_in_file}"

useful_words = words_in_file.reject { |w| useless_words.include?(w)  }

puts "Useful words in file: #{useful_words}"
```

It give me this result for my file:

```
Words in file: ["abc", "def", "to", "a", "we", "are", "we"]
Useful words in file: ["abc", "def", "to"]
```

A improved solution is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

useless_words = ["a","the","at","we","are","be","i","what", "want","you","oh","u"]

useful_words = []
File.open("file.txt", "r") do |infile|
  while (line = infile.gets)
    strip_line = line.strip
    useful_words << strip_line unless useless_words.include?(strip_line)
  end
end
```

Thanks to @T.Aoukar for his comments.

Comment: Thanks good sir, Your solution definitely works. :) I appreciate the effort

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster if you used `words_in_file - useless_words` ?? I remember reading somewhere that this would be faster but can't remember where.
Another thing is instead of pushing all words to array then selecting out the useless ones, wouldn't it be better if you didn't push them at first place? something like `words_in_file << line.strip unless useless_words.include(line.strip)`

Comment: @T.Aoukar Thanks for you comment I will add a second solution, following your suggestion. For the faster version I don't know which one is better in fact I found nothing about that (after a quick search  on the web). But you can check this presentation about how to write faster ruby script: https://speakerdeck.com/sferik/writing-fast-ruby

Comment: @T.Aoukar Just for fun I tried to run benchmark so here is my result, for `  x.report("substract")     { array_1 - array_2 }` I obtain `substract   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000066)` and for `  x.report("reject")        { array_1.reject { |v| array_2.include?(v) } }` I get `reject      0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000134)` so you have right `array1-array2` is better

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much that is one messy code, let me try to create a cleaner code for you:

```
useless_words = ['a','the','at','we','are','be','i','what', 'want','you','oh','u']
words = []
File.open(path,'r'){|f| words = f.readlines}
words = words - useless_words
puts words.count
```

When using `words - useless_words` you'll delete all elements from first array (words from file) that exist in the second array (useless_words).
Hope this is the answer you're looking for.

Comment: that didn't delete any words from the array or file